# Magento 1.9 - How to filter product reviews with status APPROVED or PENDING?

Tags: magento-1.9, review, magento1.9.3

How to get Magento product reviews of status APPROVED and/or PENDING?

None of these attempts work. Anyone know how to achieve this?

```
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection();
$reviews->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED && STATUS_PENDING)
```

or:

```
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection();
$reviews->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED && Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_PENDING)
```

or:

```
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection();
$reviews->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED || Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_PENDING)
```

What is the correct syntax to filter both Approved and Pending reviews?

So all reviews but excluding STATUS_NOT_APPROVED reviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code is correct

```
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection();
$reviews->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED || Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_PENDING)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work for me, it seems to get all reviews regardless of status.

My full code:

`$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection();`

`$reviews->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())`
   `->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED || Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_PENDING)`

            `->addEntityFilter('product', $_product->getId())`

            `->setDateOrder()`

            `->addRateVotes()`

            `->load();`

`$reviews = $reviews->getData();`

Comment: means processing status review also coming?

Comment: Yes, reviews with STATUS_NOT_APPROVED are also included.
It's like the addStatusFilter is ignored using that syntax

Comment: you can try below code 
`$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addEntityFilter('product', $productId)
    ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED || Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_PENDING)
    ->setDateOrder()
    ->addRateVotes();`

Comment: Nope couldn't get it working.
Instead I added an if statement to ignore the review if status = 3

`if (count($reviews)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($reviews); $i++) {
  if ($reviews[$i]["status_id"] != 3) {
       //print review here
}`

This works for me. Not pretty but gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. Have accepted as helpful info. This helped clarify the correct syntax. The ideal method of filtering in one go doesn't work for me (Magento 1.9.3). No idea why. Used a workaround.

Comment: ok no probllem.